# Swift 2 - Show loading view when loading Image or video from url

Tags: uiimageview, swift2, loading, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to show a loading view when fetching an image from url. I know how to do this using a `UIWebview` however, I cannot find the way to achieve this using an `UIImageView` or `MPMoviePlayerController`.

To load the image or video from Url i use:

```
 let pictureURL = NSURL(string: pictureToDisplay!)
 newsImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(pictureURL!)
```

or

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: sourceToDisplay!)
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL!)
```

Is there a way to show and hide the Loading View `loading_view.hidden = false` - `loading_view.hidden = true` when loading an url?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `NSURLConnectionDelegate`.

```
func requestNSURLconnection(url: NSURL){
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
        connection.start()
    }


    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!)
    {

        print("finishedLoading")
    }
```